# The study of a simple polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Consider the polynomial
$$
P=\prod_{k=1}^{10}\left(  X-k\right)  ^{2}+1\in\mathbb{R}\left[  X\right]  .
$$

I have to find the last four digits of $P\left(  0\right)  -2$. For doing this
I wrote
\begin{align*}
P\left(  0\right)  -2  & =\prod_{k=1}^{10}\left(  0-k\right)  ^{2}%
+1-2=2^{2}\cdot3^{2}\cdot4^{2}\cdot5^{2}\cdot6^{2}\cdot7^{2}\cdot8^{2}%
\cdot9^{2}\cdot10^{2}-1\\
& =3^{2}\cdot4^{2}\cdot6^{2}\cdot7^{2}\cdot8^{2}\cdot9^{2}\cdot10000-1\\
& =.....d0000-1,
\end{align*}
where $d$ is a non-zero digit. So the last $4$ digits are $9999$. It is
correct?

Next I have to prove that if there are $f,g\in
\mathbb{Z}
\left[  X\right]  $ such that $P=f\cdot g$, then
$$
f\left(  k\right)  =g\left(  k\right)  ,
$$
for all $k\in\left\{  1,2,\ldots,10\right\}  $. My attempt was show that the
polynomial
$$
f-g\in
\mathbb{Z}
\left[  X\right]
$$
has at least 11 roots, but I didn't find how to do that.

Comment: Yes, $P(0)-2=13168189439999$.

Comment: For the second condition, notice $P(k)=1=f(k)g(k)$ for $k=1,2,\dots,10$, which leaves only few options for integers $f(k),g(k)$